# Regarding a basis which generates K-topology

Tags: general-topology

We know that $\{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a,b)\setminus K: a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a basis for a topology called $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$, where $K=\{\dfrac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. I am searching for a member of $K$-topology, which is not there in lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Please give a hint.

Comment: Is $(a,b)-K$ for $a<0<b$ is open in lower limit topology????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The only point at which the $K$-topology really differs from the Euclidean topology is $0$, so you should look for something involving $0$. It should also be one of the non-Euclidean open sets involving $K$. What about $[0,1)\setminus K$?

Comment: @ B.M. Scott: Thank you sir for the hint...I strongly feel so, but how to show that there doesn't exist any $\epsilon>0$ such that $[0,\epsilon)\subset [0,1)\setminus K$?

Comment: @Anupam: For any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $0<\frac1n<\epsilon$. (This is the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields) of the reals.

Comment: @ B.M. Scott: Ohh...right sir! Thanks

Comment: @Anupam: You’re welcome!